# JavaScript: Search array of objects for a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

Ok, so I have an array of objects. Which get defined with a randomly generated table value. I want to search the array of objects and execute code if one table value eg. "table1" occurs more than 6 times.

Here is the array of objects I have:

```
  var data = [{
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
                {
                    name: "",
                    pref: "",
                    table: ""
                },
            ];
```

Comment: the objects have all the same value, actually ... do you have a question?

Comment: You can use a loop to iterate your array.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Just run a filter on the array, data = data.filter ( x => { return x.name === 'value_I_want' } ). When it's done, if that array has a length >= 6, run your code. Alternatively if you don't want to allocate the new array, iterate the array, look for the property, increment a counter if you find it, when that counter is === 6, break out of the loop and run your code.

Comment: @NinaScholz the values are all defined later in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for counting with condition.

ES6

```
if (data.reduce((sum, item) => sum + (item.table === "1"), 0) > 6) {
    // do something
}
```

ES5

```
if (data.reduce(function (sum, item) { return sum + (item.table === "1"); }, 0) > 6) {
    // do something
}
```

---

> ... if I use your method how can I use a while loop to run until the amount of table 1 values are less than 6?

You could use a `while` loop with a closure over the value to check for.

```
function countTable(value) {
    return function (sum, item) {
        return sum + (item.table === value);
    };
}


while (data.reduce(countTable('table1'), 0) >= 6) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I need this to change the table value until there are 6 or less 'table1' values. I have the while loop now how do I change the table value? Is there any way to do it similar to how you would do it in a for loop? Ex. data[i].table = "table2";

Comment: @jscoder001, please accept an answer before extending the question in the comments. i see actually no reason why and what property to change. you might as a new question with extended parameters.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, I'm new to SO, but I'm not as much asking you to change your code. I just need some guidance as to what to put inside the while loop. Should I ask this as another question?

Comment: it is more a question, what you wan. in the question, you ask for a occurrence of more than 6 times, now you need 6 or less. maybe you illustrate with an example what you need in a new question.

Comment: Well, I'm checking for 6 or more and changing it until there are 6 or less. I'll ask another question though unless you think you have a quick solution.

Comment: please ask. and add which items have to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example:

```
if (data.filter((item)=>{return item.table === "1"}).length >= 6)
```

Comment: Great! Now can I use that same condition in a while loop?

Comment: no, you should not use filter for counting, it is the wrong method, because you generate a result array and refuse it later.

Comment: @NinaScholz Oh, so if I use your method how can I use a while loop to run until the amount of table 1 values are less than 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.prototype.some` to stop counting if sufficient matching elements have been found.

```
function multiFind( array, property, value , count) {
    return array.some( function( c) {
        count -= c[property] == value;
        return count<=0;
    });
}
```

Alternatively this could be compressed and written in ES6 syntax as

```
var multiFind =  (a, prop, v, n) => a.some( c=> (n-=c[prop] == v)<=0);
```

Note both versions use automatic type conversion to convert boolean `true` to `1` and `false` to `0` for counting purposes. A call to the function can then be used in a conditional statement such as.

```
while( multiFind( data, "table", "table1", 6) ) {
    // do stuff while there are more than 5 "table1" table properties in data array
}
```

Comment: Ok, I almost have it working. Any chance you could tell me how I could define a variable which would allow me to manipulate any value that is "table1"? I need to move the value to another table because each table may only have 6 occupants.